# Hadoop mapred job -list output column names

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I run the command mapred job -list, I get the below output

job_1588699896018_1117890 RUNNING 1589393828518 hive root.someuser NORMAL  3   0   18432M  0M            18432M      http://some_job_track_url

I am looking for documentation for the column names and description but could not find it. If anyone has documentation or know these columns mean, it would be great if you can share.

Thanks...

Comment: Maybe source code will help: https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/tools/CLI.java#L783

Answer (score 0):

@gudok Thanks. That did the trick. The info is available in the line# 785 as of the date and time of this comment.

writer.printf(headerPattern, "JobId", "JobName", "State", "StartTime",
      "UserName", "Queue", "Priority", "UsedContainers",
      "RsvdContainers", "UsedMem", "RsvdMem", "NeededMem", "AM info");

Exactly what I was looking for. Wonder why this is not printed or if there is an option to print.